# Persistent data structure with double and subtract operations

Tags: data-structures, persistent-data-structure

I am seeking a data structure that maintains an array of N numbers and supports the following two operations:

1. Double the first i numbers
2. Subtract the first i numbers of a previous version from the current version.

It always starts with an array filled with 1s, and we only need to know the final array (after all operations have been applied).  The algorithm doesn't have to be online.  Assume overflow won't happen.

Is it possible to solve this in close to linear running time (e.g., Q log N or Q sqrt N where Q is the number of operations)?  I invented this problem for a programming contest and I'm wondering how efficiently this can be done.

Here is an example:

We start with the array `[1,1,1,1] (version 1)`

Double the first 3 numbers to get `[2,2,2,1] (version 2)`

Double the first 1 numbers to get `[4,2,2,1] (version 3)`

Subtract the first 3 numbers of version 1 to get `[3,1,1,1] (version 4)`

Subtract the first 1 numbers of version 2 to get `[2,1,1,1] (version 5)`

Then the program would output the final version: `[2,1,1,1]`

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Interesting design challenge.  Can you share the context where you encountered this problem?  I am curious about the motivation.

Comment: @D.W. actually this was part of a problem I thought of for a competitive programming challenge. The original problem was to count the number of paths in a interval graph with updates, which (hopefully) simplifies down to this problem.

Comment: Cool.  So you invented this problem?  Do you have any reason to think there is an algorithm whose running time is close to linear?

Comment: @D.W. not really :), just for fun. The non-linear solution is considered 'too easy' by some people, forcing it to be linear will make it a lot harder (may be impossible though!)

Comment: OUTPUT of N numbers on its own is O(N) that is larger than sqrt(N) or `Q*sqrt(N)` for any fixed Q

Comment: @Bulat you only need to output once at the end

Comment: Well, i tried to construct such algorithm only to find that at the end of day I need to run over all N array elements which by itself requires N operations. Without running over all array elements, how you can check that all elements were actually constructed? And anyway, it doesn't make sense to build such array faster than it can be consumed.